# being in one GIT repository, is it possible to add/commit/push files to another GIT repository using nodejs

Tags: node.js, git

I have lot of files coming from S3 and I want to add/commit/push those files to one new GIT repository using nodejs. Being in one repository can we push files to another repository? if possible, please let me know how to do that.

Comment: explore GitHub  API

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Please see this post to know how to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations